# Hide Keyboard automatically when Edit-text max length reached to it's limit

Tags: java, android

I was creating user interface where user have to enter the mobile number in EditText. maxLength of that EditText is 10. Now I want when 10 digits entered by the user the keyboard automatically get hide. How to implement this. I already searched on google but not a single code worked for me. Below is my XML & Fragment code.

XML Code

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:background="@drawable/border_design"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="@string/editText_phone_hint"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Fragment Code

```
    public class MobileNumberFragment extends Fragment {

    String mobileNumber;

            editTextNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);


    protected boolean isValidNumber(String registerMobileNumber) {
            if (registerMobileNumber != null && registerMobileNumber.length() == 10) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
 private void SendOtp() {
mobileNumber = editTextNumber.getText().toString().trim();
if (!isValidNumber(mobileNumber)) //Condition so that no edit-text will remain empty
        {
            editTextNumber.setError("Enter the Valid Mobile Number");
            editTextNumber.requestFocus();
            return;

        } else {
            buttonSendOtp.setText("Processing...");
}

    }
```

Comment: That sounds like an annoying UI feature.  Suppose I make a typing error which I do not immediately notice. If I understand you correctly, I type the 10th digit, the keyboard vanishes, and I can't correct my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), calling [`hideSoftInputFromWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29), passing in the token of the window containing your focused view.

// Check if no view has focus:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length() == 10){
                HideKeyboardFormUser();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void HideKeyboardFormUser(){
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager hideKeyboard  = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    hideKeyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow( view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

}

This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases you will want to pass in `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).

Answer (score 0):

```
editTextNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() >= 10) {
                editTextNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                editTextNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a TextWatcher listener to the EditText, and hide the keyboard once the length reached 10.

```
    editTextNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

    editTextNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 10){
                hideSoftKeyboard(requireActivity());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    View currentFocus = activity.getCurrentFocus();

    if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        IBinder windowToken = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

        if (currentFocus != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```